# Integral representation of the Beta function

Tags: calculus, integration, beta-function

How do I get from $ \int_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1}\,\mathrm dt} $  to $ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}{ \frac{t^{x-1} + t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \,\mathrm dt} $ ? I have tried different change of variables but without success.

Comment: it seems "the second" defintion of yours for beta needs to be divided by 2 and the integral should be over 0 to infinity :-)

Comment: the second formula or $ \int_{1}^{ \infty }{ \frac{t^{x-1} + t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \,dt} $ is true and yours also. but how to get it.

Comment: hi Joanpemo could you explain the last step?. Also, you should have $z^{y-1}$ instead of $z^{y+1}$ in the integral before the last integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute

$$\frac1u=t\implies dt=-\frac{du}{u^2}\implies$$

$$\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt=\int_\infty^1u^{1-x}\left(1-\frac1u\right)^{y-1}\left(-\frac{du}{u^2}\right)=\int_1^\infty u^{1-x}u^{1-y}(u-1)^{y-1}u^{-2}du=$$

$$=\int_1^\infty u^{-(x+y)}(u-1)^{y-1}du=:I$$

and now substitute

$$u=z+1\implies du=dz\implies I=\int_0^\infty(z+1)^{-(x+y)}z^{y-1}dz=$$

$$=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{x-1}+z^{y-1}}{(z+1)^{x+y}}dz$$

Comment: @user343539 Any time

Comment: hi Joanpemo could you explain the last step?. Also, you should have $ z^{y−1}$ instead of $ z^{y+1}$ in the integral before the last integral.

Comment: @xxx The exponents was a typo which has already been corrected, thank you. Observe that $\;z^{y-1}\;$ and $\;z^{x-1}\;$ are the same in the integral as $\;x,y\;$ are only parameters and they both are symmetric with respect to the denominator $\;(z+1)^{x+y}\;$ , so the last integral is twice the one before it, and because of it there is $\;\frac12\;$ multiplying.

Comment: Thank you Joanpemo. I got it